# How to decompress compiled qt resource file with rcc extension?

Tags: qt, winapi, rcc

How to decompress compiled qt resource file with rcc extension?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

rcc is not a file format. It's Qt's resource compiler. It doesn't create a resource file either. It converts the resources specified in your qrc file into a C++ source file and lets C++ compiler compile it into object code to be linked into your app.

Look for qrc_yourproject.cpp in your build directory to see what's produced. Do not try to access the objects/structures defined in the file directly since Qt may change how they are constructed in later versions. Use Qt's resource management calls to do that.

Comment: It is also possible to create a binary file from the .qrc file, external to your app, with rcc, that can be loaded at runtime. See [External binary resources](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/resources.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer did not meet my needs, I thought I'd post my experience in this.

I wrote a node module that will extract PNG files from QT binary rcc files. It is available on npm as [png-extractor](https://www.npmjs.org/package/png-extractor) if you are interested.

Comment: Good one, but I suppose you need to add the size of the endMatch + 1 to the chunk, otherwise it wouldn't add the footer the the chunk!